# How to restrict a module to a specific core version?

Tags: 8, .info

Drupal 8.3 introduced some changes, which broke a custom module; fixing the changes causes the module to break in previous Drupal versions. One way to handle this would be to require Drupal core to above version 8.3+ for this module. However, the following changes to YAML file does not work.

```
core: '8.3'
core: '8.3.x'
```

Drupal shows the following incompatibility message.

> This version is not compatible with Drupal 8.x and should be replaced.

The official documentation does not provide useful information for [core](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file) keyword.

So how should Drupal core version requirement specified in the .info file? If not, is there any other way to specify such requirement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using *core* only supports the major version, but you can add a dependency on the system.module with a specific version.

```
dependencies:
 - system (>=8.3)
```

Due to a bug in version parsing, you can only do this with the minor version. You can't specify a patch release like 8.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in [hook_requirements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/8.3.x) like so:

```
function mymodule_requirements($phase) {
  // code
  $version = \Drupal::VERSION;
  // code that checks version info here

  return $requirements;
}
```

If `$version` is not what you're expecting, throw a REQUIREMENT_ERROR. In fact, there is sort of an example on the docs page.

```
function mymodule_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = [];

  // code
  $version = explode('.', \Drupal::VERSION);
  // code that checks version info here

  if ($version[0] == 8 && $version[1] < 3) {
    $requirements['mymodule'] = [
      'title' => t('My Module'),
      'description' => t('This module requires Drupal 8.3.0 or higher before it can be installed.'),
      'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR
    ];
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code stub. This seems like overlooked item in D8 core. Does this warrant submitting an issue to core?

Comment: No, this is valid, see Berdir's answer for another valid approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'll choose @Berdir's answer as that'll work once hooks are deprecated or eliminated in 9.x