# Can I define the minimum php version for my module in my .info.yml file?

Tags: 8, .info

I need to define the minimum PHP version in my module.info.yml file but I don't know if this is posible using:

```
php: 5.6
```

If you search about this in the drupal.org documentation you will only see the reference about this in the theme.info.yml file: [Defining a theme with an .info.yml file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/defining-a-theme-with-an-infoyml-file)

> **php (optional)**
>
> The minimum version of PHP required. Defaults to value
>   of `DRUPAL_MINIMUM_PHP` constant.
>
> `php: 5.5.9`

But in the documentation about the module.info.yml file there is nothing about the php version: [Let Drupal 8 know about your module with an .info.yml file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file).

So, really I can't define the minimum php version in my module.info.yml file?

Comment: A similar question was asked here. It is definitely doable from the install file. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234343/specify-core-version-requirement-for-a-custom-module/234344?noredirect=1#comment287817_234344

Comment: @Kevin thanks, I read your answer the last week, is very good, I think that maybe the doc page don't have all the information, because I see that in drupal 7 is posible to do this. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x#php I will made some test to see what happens.

Comment: If you are looking for additional documentation this might be a good place to start - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/8.2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the answer to a question is best found by trying. If you add `php: 8.0` to your module.info.yml file you will see this:

[image: incompatible module]

So it can still be used. (I have updated the linked documentation as well.)

Comment: This is a complete example from Drupal on what variables can be used in the info.yml file https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file#s-complete-example